# Can I call a variable created with javascript in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can I call a variable whose path is in /public/assets/js in my React project within useEffect() in React views?

For example, can I use jsVal like below?

```
useEffect(() => {
   const existingScript = jsVal.getSum();
   ...
}
```

The reason why I am curious is because, when the screen made with React is turned on with chrome, jsVal is not 'jsVal is not defined' in the Console Tab of Developer Tools.

However, in useEffect, jsVal comes out as 'can not find Name', so I leave a question.

Add The location where jsVal is defined is /public/assets/js/test.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your value is exposed in some way through `global` or `window` then yes, you can access it in React!

i.e.

```js
// public/assets/file.js
window.jsVal = {
  getSum(a, b) { return a + b; }
}

// In case of typescript, add an ambient declaration too!
declare global {
  interface Window {
    jsVal: {
      getSum(a: number, b: number): number;
    }
  }
}

// React app (make sure file.js is included before React app bundle in index.html)
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      setVal(window.jsVal.getSum(10, 32)); // 42
    },
    [window.jsVal, setVal]
  );

  return null;
}
```

Comment: I put jsVal in test.js var jsVal= jsVal || {}; defined it.

you answered
What if I can't access it with window.jsVal?

Comment: Property 'jsVal' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'. comes out. ;(

Comment: As a result of checking Developer Tools Tab/Sources/Scope through breakpoint, I confirmed that jsVal is in Global. Can this part I found be helpful to my question?

Comment: declare global {
    interface Window {
        jsVal:any;
    }
}
I added , and the desired function was completed. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the ambient declaration, so that it may help other people maybe ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume `jsVal` is a global service/variable ? If so.

Everything of React is javascript. You can think React is a global variable.

```
  React.render(<App />, el)
```

So in general, it depends on if `jsVal` is defined early or later than `render`. However `useEffect` is also a bit special. It actually fires in another Javascript task/tick, similar to `setTimeout` or an API, so its execution is deferred in async way.

Comment: If test.js is included in public/index.html in my project, which part of your answer corresponds to?

Also, jsVal is var jsVal= jsVal || in test.js. {}; defined it.

Comment: As a result of checking Developer Tools Tab/Sources/Scope through breakpoint, I confirmed that jsVal is in Global. Can this part I found be helpful to my question?